# Generate a C# expression that can concatenate two strings together

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-core

I'm trying to concatenate two strings together in a dynamic linq expression. The parameter I pass to the function must be a `Dictionary<string, object>`. The problem is that The Expression.Add throws me an error because it doesn't know how to add strings.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
x => (string)x["FirstName"] + " Something here..."
```

What I have:

```
var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), "x");
var firstName = Expression.Call(pe, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod("get_Item"), Expression.Constant("FirstName"));
var prop = Expression.Convert(firstName, typeof(string));
var exp = Expression.Add(prop, Expression.Constant(" Something here..."))
```

Comment: Does your Dictionary<string,object> has FirstName as a string? {Key:"FirstName",Value:"Andoni"}?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding strings is neither one of the types that expressions handles explicitly (as it does for numeric primitives) nor going to work due to an overload of `+` (since `string` has no such overload), so you need to explicitly defined the method that should be called when overloading:

```
Expression.Add(
  prop,
  Expression.Constant(" Something here..."),
  typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new []{typeof(string), typeof(string)}))
```

This makes the overload of `string.Concat` that takes two string arguments the method used.

You could also use `Expresssion.Call` but this keeps your `+` intention explicit (and is what the C# compiler does when producing expressions, for that reason).

Comment: maybe it's not very important but for compile, add a comma ( , ) at the end of second parameter.